# Custom page control with image for current dot larger than rest not working

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have used some previous solutions. The following code from stackoverflow helps but the current dot doesn't show larger than the rest (although image named: "currentPageDot" is larger than UIImage(named: "defaultPageDot")). Also I don't want to disturb their position while they become larger. How should I modify this code to do the same.

How it looks:

[image: How it looks]

How it should look:

[image: How it should look]

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class EnhancedPageControl: UIPageControl {

    let activeImage:UIImage = UIImage(named: "currentPageDot")!
    let inactiveImage:UIImage = UIImage(named: "defaultPageDot")!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        self.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.clear
        self.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.clear
        self.clipsToBounds = false
    }

    func updateDots() {
        var i = 0
        for view in self.subviews {
            if let imageView = self.imageForSubview(view) {
                if i == self.currentPage {
                    imageView.image = nil
                    imageView.image = self.activeImage
                } else {
                    imageView.image = nil
                    imageView.image = self.inactiveImage
                }
                i = i + 1
            } else {
                var dotImage = self.inactiveImage
                if i == self.currentPage {
                    dotImage = self.activeImage
                }
                view.clipsToBounds = false
                view.addSubview(UIImageView(image:dotImage))
                i = i + 1
            }
        }
    }

    fileprivate func imageForSubview(_ view:UIView) -> UIImageView? {
        var dot:UIImageView?

        if let dotImageView = view as? UIImageView {
            dot = dotImageView
        } else {
            for foundView in view.subviews {
                if let imageView = foundView as? UIImageView {
                    dot = imageView
                    break
                }
            }
        }

        return dot
    }
}
```

Comment: Rather than subclass `UIPageControl` it would probably be easier just to write your own from scratch. Maybe using a horizontal `UIStackView` to contain your dots?

Answer (score 0):

Try not changing the image, but playing with transform property on page control subviews. Something like this

```
 pageControl.subviews[pageControl.currentPage].transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.5, y: 1.5)
```

Comment: This doesn't work - the dot ends up out of line with the others.